# passing data to google chart at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I have been trying to create a google chart. It works if i hard code the value in DrawChart Function but it doesn't work when i pass the value from aspx.cs page, it only gives blank page.
i don't know where i am making the mistake.
below is the HTML and C# code

HTML Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Chart2.aspx.cs" Inherits="CarriageReturn.Chart2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Chart2.aspx/GetChartData()",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
              success: function (r) {
             var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        chartdata.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

           chartdata.addRows(r.d);

                         // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(chartdata, options);
             },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
          });
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CarriageReturn
{
    public partial class Chart2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetChartData();
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<object> GetChartData()
        {
            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Mushrooms", 3 });
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Onions", 1 });
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Olives", 1 });
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Zucchini", 1 });
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Pepperoni", 1 });
            return chartData;


        }
    }
}
```

i need to pass the value to chart from database.

Comment: It looks like you aren't registering the PageLoad() event.  Put a break point in the Load event and check if you are getting to the code.  if not you need to add a constructor for the Char2 class and then register the event with "+=".

Comment: did you check the console for errors? will you please share a sample of --> `r.d`?

Comment: not getting any error message, i have pasted whole code here